# Can twitter4j fetch more than 1 picture from a tweet?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am new to twitter4j and i try to fetch a couple of tweets, it all work fine except for the tweets with multiple pictures.

For example, if i tweet 4 pictures at the same time (yes now twitter allow us to tweet up to 4 pictures from their mobile application), i only manage to fetch the 1st picture.here is my code:

```
        for (twitter4j.Status status : result.getTweets()) {
            if (status.getMediaEntities() != null)
            {
                    for (MediaEntity media : status.getMediaEntities())
                    {
                        //for some reason getMediaEntities() return an array with the first pic uploaded only
                    }   
            }
        }
```

Tahnks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `status.getExtendedMediaEntities()`